# Add inline policy to aws SAM template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-sam

I'm using SAM Template to create my serverless application.

Using the tag `Policies` under the properties of the resource I can add *standard* policies like this:

```
Resources:
  QueryFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: query/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Policies:
        - AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
        - AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
      Runtime: python3.7
```

The problem is that I need to attach an inline policy to access only a specific DynamoDB table.

How can i put this inline policy in the template?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "dynamodb:*",
            "Resource": "dynamo_db_table_endpoint"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
QueryFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: query/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Policies:
        - AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
        - AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
        - Version: '2012-10-17' # Policy Document
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - dynamodb:*
              Resource: 'arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/dynamo_db_table_endpoint'
      Runtime: python3.7
```

[Amazon DynamoDB: Allows Access to a Specific Table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_dynamodb_specific-table.html)

If you would like to pass your **tableName** as parameter change `Resource: 'arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/dynamo_db_table_endpoint'` to 
`Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:dynamodb:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:table/${tableName}'`

Hope this helps

Comment: @rivamarco any luck with that?

Comment: Can we add multiple resources in this?
ex:
Resource: [<arn1>,<arn2>]

Comment: I'm aware i'm adding to this a year late, but can you only attach the PolicyDocument section or is there a way to build a Policy that adds existing Roles too? e.g. The final example on this page:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-policy.html

Comment: this isnt working for me in 2023... something changed?

Comment: @AriWaisberg did you find a solution to this? I can confirm it's not working for me either as of May 2023.

Comment: @AriWaisberg can you explain that approach of commands please? I desire to follow that approach, but for now did not understand you comment.