# AWS SAM Lambda policy for OpenSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, aws-sam, opensearch

I couldn't get a valid IAM policy to work for a Lambda function to OpenSearch.

```
  Replicate:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-Replicate
      Description: !Sub
        - Stack ${StackTagName} Environment ${EnvironmentTagName} Function ${ResourceName}
        - ResourceName: DBReplicate
      CodeUri: ../src/Replicate
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs16.x
      MemorySize: 3008
      Timeout: 30
      Tracing: Active
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: Access
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - es:*
            Resource:
              - arn:aws:es:eu-west-1:22222222222:domain/mynewdomain
              - DomainName: mynewdomain
      Events:
        MyDynamoDBtable:
          Type: DynamoDB
          Properties:
            Stream: !Ref TableStreamArn
            StartingPosition: TRIM_HORIZON
            BatchSize: 1
```

Running `sam validate`, I'm getting:

> Policy at index 0 in the 'Policies' property is not valid

Comment: Are you sure that `DomainName: mynewdomain` is valid on Resource? Suspect it is not and should simply be an ARN. See resource examples in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/ac.html).

Comment: I tried arn directly in front of the Resource, the same

Comment: Did you remove `- DomainName: mynewdomain` entirely? What happened?

Comment: Yes, also removed, still won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from another post, the structure was wrong, the correct way is:
[Add inline policy to aws SAM template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59249717/add-inline-policy-to-aws-sam-template)

```
QueryFunction:
Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
Properties:
  CodeUri: query/
  Handler: app.lambda_handler
  Policies:
    - AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
    - AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
    - Version: '2012-10-17' # Policy Document
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - dynamodb:*
          Resource: 'arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/dynamo_db_table_endpoint'
```